# installing and using python-oauth2

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0

I installed oauth2:

```
$ pip install oauth2
```

But running the python-oauth2/example/client.py returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 31, in <module>
    import oauth.oauth as oauth
ImportError: No module named oauth.oauth
```

I tested pip freeze:

```
oauth2==1.5.211
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a local module named `oauth` in your directory? Does `import oauth` work? If so, what does `print(oauth.__file__)` give you?

Comment: Hi Martijn. No local module. I obtained `>>> print(oauth.__file__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'oauth' is not defined`  import oauth return: `import oauth
ImportError: No module named oauth`

Comment: That eliminates at least one common error. If you run `head \`which plip\`` it'll tell you what python you installed the package into; are you certain that that is the same python you are using for the example?

Comment: It seems that the example directory codes (`https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2`) are for oauth not for oauth2. right?

Comment: That is the other option, that the `example` directory is b0rken and using the wrong package names. :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the `example` directory in the `oauth2` package should be ignored. It is broken code as far as the package is concerned.

See these issues for examples of other people discovering this:

- https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/issues/33
- https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/issues/12
- https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/pull/64

The last one is a pull request that includes *new* examples to use instead.